# How to sum all integer properties from ForeignKey objects in django template?

Tags: python, django, templates

In my models, each product has variations, and each variation has `orderitem`. Each `orderitem` has integer value which is quantity.

Is there a way in Django template to add all of the quantities of a particular product and display it?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Orderitem(models.Model):
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # I want to display the sum of this
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

Comment: Don't do logic in the templates. That's what views or models are for.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

1 - product.get_total_order()
If you'll reuse this somewhere, you can add a method in the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_total_order(self):
         return ...
```

and display it in the template:

```
{{ product.get_total_order }}
```

---

2.In the view
If you never reuse that information:

```
def your_view(request, ...):
     return render(request, template_name...html, {'total_order': xxx})
```

Template:

```
{{ total_order }}
```

---

3.As a template tag
If you'll re-use it, but you don't like the first option (to keep the model light), you could add a filter tag:

```
{{ product|product_total_order }}
```

---

Notes / comments:

- please post the code you've tried if you can't figure it out
- Orderitem => OrderItem
- I highly recommend to add `related_name` in your foreign keys